# Ora - 00088 error: command cannot be executed by shared server

Tags: oracle, dataguard

I get this error from the database when I run the query:

```
select status, error from v$archive_dest where dest_id=2;
```

It's a dataguard environment. I have never seen this problem before.

I'm not quite sure what this means or how it can be fixed.

What is generally the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding (SERVICE=Dedicated) to your TNS entry on the client computer that you are using and then run your query again.

There could be other causes but this is the most common:  you are trying to access data using a shared connection when a dedicated connection is required.

Edit: Are there any other log or trace file entries when this error happens?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to find out what in this DG environment is making this happen but it seems to be oracle's internal sauce. The weird part is our install is very standard. Same everywhere and yet this time it decides to show this...

Comment: You didn't mention on which release you are?

Comment: it's release 10.2.0.5